# Limit tag autocompleting in search

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, search

It is great that we have the auto-completion of tags in the search box. When I enter i.e.

```
[*sql*]
```

then all the SQL tags get included in my search automatically and I have a live refresh on them in a single browser tab. That way I can watch my favorite tags in real time on Stack Overflow which is really awesome!

**Manually I can enter up to 250 characters in the search box. But with this auto-completion I can overcome this**. Try i.e.

```
[*api*] or [*sql*] or [*xml*] or [*css*]
```

You can extend that to watch almost everything in SO in realtime. Is that OK?

Comment: What's the bug? That the search isn't limited?

Comment: Exactly.­­­­­­­

Comment: I am trying to find it, but I'm almost certain this is in response to a recent feature-request complaining that wildcards defaulted to `AND` instead of `OR` statements within the wildcards. So it would be `[a-api] and [b-api] or [c-sql] and [d-sql]` instead of all `or`s.

Comment: I can't try that, my company's firewall resets connection if I try ;)

Comment: I didn't know that was an option. TIL.