# My tags list cuts off, leaving out some relevant tags

Tags: bug, tags, tag-watching, my-tags

I often use [My tags](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?sort=Newest&tagMode=Watched&uqlId=8) to filter questions. Today I noticed that some questions with relevant tags were excluded from the filtered list. The culprit seems to be that the list of tags (which is pretty long in my case) cuts off at some point, leaving some relevant tags out (the ones that are towards the end of the alphabet). This happens on three different browsers that I have tried. What do I do to fix that?

Comment: No idea what is "my tags". The link you posted is to the site questions list, nothing special there. Please clarify what you mean, and post screenshot of the problem.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard That's a link to a filter, which only works for the person who made it. "My tags" is an option for filters which uses watched tags.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard, yes, the link only works if you have your list of watched tags on the site. It is there to show what it refers to in general, not the content of my (Richard's) followed tags. Also, check out the [`my-tags`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/my-tags/info) tag that you will find under my post. It explains the concept.

Comment: I see. Think it's limited to 25 tags to prevent overloading the server, however try [this link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=intags%3Amine), does it work and showing all your tags?

Comment: [This one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204316/too-many-tags-requested-search-limited-to-25-tags) might have the answer.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard, yes, the first link works. It delivers questions and answers separately, so I get about twice as many results as I used to, but it is still a pretty good solution.

Comment: @RichardHardy you can add `is:q` to the search box, or click [this updated link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=intags%3Amine+is%3Aq), to see only questions. That's using the ordinary search mechanism, which isn't limited.

Comment: @ShadowTheSpringWizard, I suppose you could post your comments as an answer, as they did solve my problem.

Comment: @RichardHardy you should mark the answer as accepted. Since you said it resolved your issues and asked for it to be an answer. Getting rep is always nice

Comment: @BigJoe, done. Just waited a bit for any other answers before accepting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "My Tags" feature is limited to 50 tags, as mentioned in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368704/152859).

That isn't likely going to change, so a simple workaround is using the search mechanism to achieve same goal (The search isn't limited for logged in users). You can use the `intags:mine` operator to get results which have one of your watched tags, and to get only questions, add the `is:q` search operator.

That said, the existing behavior can be improved by adding a message when the user has more than 50 tags, e.g. "Only the first 50 Watched Tags are used", to avoid confusion.

Comment: Pretty sure search is limited — but only by character length, which shouldn't be a problem here if you're using `intags:mine`.